# Chrome extension refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' in emscripten generated file

Tags: javascript, web, google-chrome-extension, webassembly, emscripten

I'm trying to load up a wasm module in my Chrome plugin. Chrome complains about the following function in the wasm module generated by emscripten. It trips on the following js

`Uncaught EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' blob: filesystem:".`

```
function createNamedFunction(name, body) {
      name = makeLegalFunctionName(name);
      /*jshint evil:true*/
      return new Function(
          "body",
          "return function " + name + "() {\n" +
          "    \"use strict\";" +
          "    return body.apply(this, arguments);\n" +
          "};\n"
      )(body);
    }
```

I'm loading the script in the `background.html` file so it can behave as a module . .

```
<script type="module" src="../js/background.js"></script>
<script type="module" src="../js/AudioWorkletProcessor.js"></script>
<script type="module" src="../js/kernel.wasmmodule.js"></script>
```

How are people getting around this with web assembly in their plugins?

Comment: Does `-s NO_DYNAMIC_EXECUTION=1` work?

Comment: @zakki yes! Put that as an answer for me to accept!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`-s NO_DYNAMIC_EXECUTION=1` removes `eval()` and `new Function()` from generated code.

https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/blob/master/src/settings.js#L1030

> When set to 0, we do not emit eval() and new Function(), which disables some functionality
> (causing runtime errors if attempted to be used), but allows the emitted code to be
> acceptable in places that disallow dynamic code execution (chrome packaged app,
> privileged firefox app, etc.). Pass this flag when developing an Emscripten application
> that is targeting a privileged or a certified execution environment, see
> Firefox Content Security Policy (CSP) webpage for details:
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Build/Building_apps_for_Firefox_OS/CSP
> When this flag is set, the following features (linker flags) are unavailable:
> --closure 1: When using closure compiler, eval() would be needed to locate the Module object.
> -s RELOCATABLE=1: the function Runtime.loadDynamicLibrary would need to eval().
> --bind: Embind would need to eval().
> Additionally, the following Emscripten runtime functions are unavailable when
> DYNAMIC_EXECUTION=0 is set, and an attempt to call them will throw an exception:
>
> - emscripten_run_script(),
> - emscripten_run_script_int(),
> - emscripten_run_script_string(),
> - dlopen(),
> - the functions ccall() and cwrap() are still available, but they are restricted to only
>   being able to call functions that have been exported in the Module object in advance.
>
> When set to -s DYNAMIC_EXECUTION=2 flag is set, attempts to call to eval() are demoted
> to warnings instead of throwing an exception.

Comment: where do I put this config?